# Alterar background de acordo com a imagem

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

Estou precisando criar um efeito no meu slideshow de que para cada imagem, o fundo da `div` troca de cor de acordo com a cor predominante da mesma. Procurei na internet um plugin que faça isso, e achei o `Adaptive.Background.js`.

No geral ele funciona perfeitamente, o único problema é que a cor do fundo não vai atualizando de acordo com o passar dos slides, ele troca no primeiro ato e não troca mais. Para o slider, estou usando o plugin `bxslider`.

::::: HTML do Slider

```
<div class="banner" id="tween-banner">
    <div class="wrapp">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li><img src="image1.jpg" alt="Nome 1" /></li>
            <li><img src="image2.jpg" alt="Nome 2" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

:::: jQuery

```
SC('.bxslider').bxSlider({ 
    auto:true,
    easing:'easeInOutCubic',
    useCSS:false,
    speed: 1000
})
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Uma alternativa que pensei é inserir a cor manualmente para cada imagem.
Exemplo:

```
<img src="imagem1.jpg" setcolor="#666333" />
<img src="imagem2.jpg" setcolor="#FF0033" />
```

Nisso, eu executaria um `jQuery` que pegasse o valor `setcolor` e aplicasse como fundo na `div`. Mas não tenho muito conhecimento de como posso criar essa variável dentro da `<img>`.

Comment: Ricardo, pode colocar o código que já tem? Assim podemos ajudar no que está a falhar. No HTML pode usar `data-color="#666333"` e no jQuery usar o `.data()`, ie `$(img).data('color')` para ler, e `$(img).data('color', '#123456')` para atribuir nova cor.

Comment: Ótimo! Não conhecia esse `data-color`. Agora preciso identificar qual é o slide atual, para ele pegar esse atributo e aplicar ao `background` da div.

Comment: Acho que precisa dar uma olhada á opcão `onSlideNext` nesta página: http://bxslider.com/options

Comment: O StackFiddle já está funcionando ([*Apresentando: JS, CSS e HTML executáveis!*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/201)), ver o problema ao vivo e aqui mesmo é sempre legal :)

Comment: Eles poderiam colocar exemplos visíveis para entender melhor no site do bxSlider. :\

Comment: Consegui, @Sergio :D como você me disse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui.

Adicionei `data-color="COR"` as `<img>` do meu slideshow e depois modifiquei o `jQuery` para executar a função de leitura da cor e adicioná-la ao fundo da `div`.

Exemplo de como ficou:

```
<div class="banner" id="tween-banner">
    <div class="wrapp">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li><img src="image1.jpg" alt="Nome 1" data-color="#CC33CC" class="img-slider" /></li>
            <li><img src="image2.jpg" alt="Nome 2" data-color="#999999" class="img-slider" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

e no jQuery:

```
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({ 
        auto:true,
        easing:'easeInOutCubic',
        useCSS:false,
        speed: 1000,
        onSlideNext: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
            var corSlide = $('.img-slider').eq( newIndex ).data('color');
            $('.banner').css({ 'background-color': corSlide });
        }
    });
```

Obrigado ao @Sergio que me orientou.

Comment: Excelente! Provavelmente a sua resposta será util para outros.