# Alterar background-image da div de acordo com a imagem do banner

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, bxslider

Estou precisando criar um efeito no meu slideshow que para cada imagem exibida no slideshow o fundo da `div class="banner-backg"` troque o background-image.

Para o slider estou usando o http://bxslider.com/options

**: HTML do Slider**

```
<div class="banner-backg">
    <div class="banner-center">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li><img src="images/banner_1.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/banner_2.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/banner_3.png" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**: jQuery**

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    mode: 'fade',
    auto:true,
    easing:'easeInOutCubic',
    useCSS:false,
    speed: 1000
});
```

Uma alternativa que pensei foi inserir o background-image manualmente para cada imagem. Exemplo:

```
            <li><img src="images/banner_1.png" setimg="images/background_1jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/banner_2.png" setimg="images/background_2jpg" /></li>
```

Nisso, eu executaria um jQuery que pegasse o valor `setimg` e aplicasse como fundo na `div class="banner-backg"`. Mas não tenho muito conhecimento de como posso criar essa variável dentro da `img`.

Comment: Você pode fazer isso com funções Callbacks, na documentação dele tem como fazer.

Comment: Tentei usar o onSlideNext mas só funciona trocando a cor do fundo, não sei como posso capturar o caminho da imagem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua HTML você coloca assim:

```
<div class="banner-backg">
<div class="banner-center">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="images/banner_1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/banner_2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/banner_3.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Considere que na pasta **images** tenha os arquivos listados abaixo e a biblioteca **jquery** com a versão que implemente **.css()**:
**background_1.jpg

background_2.jpg

background_3.jpg**
E no script você faz algo como isso:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    mode: 'fade',
    auto:true,
    easing:'easeInOutCubic',
    useCSS:false,
    speed: 1000,
    onSlideNext: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
   // var tamanho = {'width':'100%', 'height':'auto'};
         $('.bxslider')
          .css({'background':'url(images/background_' + newIndex + '.jpg) center center no-repeat'})
        //  .css(tamanho)
        ;  
  }
});
```

Comment: Não testei, mas veja lá.

Comment: Valeu a tentativa mas não funcionou Ivan, olha essa resposta aqui do Ricardo. ele conseguiu fazer funcionar com COR, no meu caso eu só queria trocar a cor por imagem. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36892/alterar-background-de-acordo-com-a-imagem/36916#36916

Comment: Cara, é a mesma lógica, newIndex seria o número da imagem: background_1.jpg, background_2.jpg, background_2.jpg, etc... o que eu fiz, na verdade foi acessar o parent() do elemento, que no caso é <ul>, e colocar uma imagem de fundo. Só coloca a imagem como background.

Comment: Muito bom Ivan... funcionou sim... só que ao invés de colocar o background para aparecer na div .bxslider eu coloquei na div .banner-backg .... muito obrigado pela ajuda, me salvou aqui.